# Generating Excel from Angular - Header Error

Tags: angular, exceljs

I am trying to follow the example given below in `Angular 6`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exceljs-sample?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fexcel.service.ts

Here it throws error at header as below in `excel.service.ts`

[image: Header Error]

How to correct it?

Comment: `uniqueHeaders.forEach((header: string, j) => {...`

Comment: Thanks @peinearydevelopment. It is resolved.